# Why my code generate at the and the arrays of keys: "0"

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I created a cache from xml, and by a construct I generate the object which finally become the arrays. And everything would be ok, if the key of these arrays wasnt "0". I dont know how it works. I searched the information how to change the class, or how to replace the keys. I am stuck. Could you help me with this.

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($cache);
}

class  Property {
    public $xmlClass;
    public $elemClass = '';
    public $result_array = [];
    public $data = '';
 public function __construct($xml,$elem) {
    $this->xmlClass=$xml;
    $this->elemClass=$elem;

  foreach($xml->list->movie as $value) {
    $data = $value->$elem;
    $this->result_array[] = $data;
  }
}
public function getResult() {
    return $this->result_array;
}
}

 $result_zn = new Property($xml,'zn');
 $result_au = new Property($xml,'au');
 $result_ti = new Property($xml, 'ti');



 $zn = $result_zn->getResult();
 $au = $result_au->getResult();
 $ti = $result_ti->getResult();
```

Comment: This question is not clear

Comment: Everything works, but this code(constructor) generates the data in which i have the keys = "0". That`s how I see this when I try to catch this data and work with it after. Its impossible.

Comment: Unclear what you mean by that.

Comment: Can you show an example of the code which is having problems getting the data you want.  At the end you should be able to do `$zn[0]`, `$zn[1]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the function array_values() to get the key 0,like this:

```
$arr = array(
        '1' => 'cat',
        '2' => 'dog'
    );
$newarr = array_values($arr);
print_r($newarr);
```

and the result is :

```
Array ( [0] => cat [1] => dog )
```